# My Highchart is stepping back to 01/18/1970 everytime. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfj6S.png)
is my Highchart. On the right the X axis value is correct (2017.08.03). But when it starts to step, it steps backwards, to 01/18/1970. The Y value is correct also. Here is an example from my JSON data:

```
[[1501746396.26,22.96],[1501746396.26,24.2],[1501746396.26,28.55],[1501746396.26,27.54],[1501746396.26,22.12]
```

The first value is the current UNIX-time, the second is the Y-value. Here is an example, how I add point to my series.

```
chart.series[i].addPoint(dataa[i], true, shift);
```

While debugging I've noticed, that it received the correct data. (I've logged chart.series[i].data, it has points.) Also at inicialize it receives the correct data, but at inicialize it doesn't work from this JSON file, it works from another JSON file.

Comment: Just at a quick glance, that timestamp is in seconds, right? Highcharts expects timestamps in milliseconds. Maybe try `dataa[i] * 1000` or see if seconds/milliseconds is related.

Comment: Correct, thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: The "zero" of [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is Jan. 1, 1970.  00:00 UTC;  That's why mis-scaling time in the data by 1000 is producing dates in 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to multiple my value with 1000 to get milliseconds, because Highcharts expects milliseconds. :)